# EDMX and ENUM Error: The type or namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, enums

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET 4.5 application with EF 6 and DB First. When I do some changes on my database and further on import the new table into my .edmx  I'm very often running into the following very annoying error:

**The type or namespace could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

*The problem is: I have some tables mapped to enums, and after my update they are not linked correctly anymore.*

I usually end up recreating the whole .edmx file (delete all tables, and re-import them, etc).

Do you know a way how to preserve the mapping of enums to tables and save the namespace somehow?

This is really annoying :/

Comment: There is no other way .... Updating edmx like that is essential thing....

Comment: maybe switching to Code First... :P

Comment: nah ... you have to do it always